# Foreign key reference object is returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate, navigation-properties

I am referencing the `AbpUser` table in an entity with the following property definition:

```
[ForeignKey("LocationManagerId")]
public virtual User LocationManager { get; set; }
public virtual long LocationManagerId { get; protected set; }
```

My DTO is as follows:

```
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(Location))]
public class LocationDto : FullAuditedEntityDto<Guid>
{
    // <snip>
    public virtual User LocationManager { get; set; }
}
```

Using the `AsyncCrudAppService` and calling the following from an MVC controller:

```
var locations = (await _locationAppService.GetAll(new PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto())).Items;
```

`locations.LocationManager` is returning `null`.  I've confirmed everything in both the entity and the DTO is set to `virtual`. I'm at a loss. Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using EntityFrameworkCore, you have to use eager-loading.

Override this method in `LocationAppService`:

```
protected override IQueryable<Location> CreateFilteredQuery(LocationGetAllInput input)
{
    return Repository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.LocationManager);
}
```